# Can't create/write to file 'C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\Data#sql_29c_0.MYI' (Errcode: 17)

Tags: mysql, files

Whenever I am doing a backup, I get this error.

I checked the net for this error and have done the following things:

1. Create a folder in MySQL\Temp and changed the temporary directory of MySQL temp directory path to newly created one and excluded the newly created folder from Antivirus Scan.
2. Given full permissions to the newly created temporary folder.
3. Free space is allocated to that drive.

Even after doing these changes, I am not able to take a backup, and this is happening every time.

Is any thing else I had missed out for this one?

Comment: Please show the line you used in my.ini to define datadir and tmpdir

Answer (score 1):

I saw something like this in this URL but it about ErrCode 13

http://beerpla.net/2010/01/05/how-to-fix-intermittent-mysql-errcode-13-errors-on-windows/

This one on ErrCode 17

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=25872

Check to make sure your AntiVirus software isn't wacking the temp file.

Hope this helps !!!